# What's the name for a podium with numbers?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I don't know what this is called. Is it a podium?

[image]

Comment: see https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=podium http://www.daily-chronicle.com/2013/05/06/never-again-confuse-lectern-for-a-podium/b57qunb/ and https://www.google.com/search?q=competition+podium&espv=2&biw=864&bih=1455&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7hoPxudjNAhXLeD4KHV4uBE4Q_AUIBigB

Comment: It's a **podium**. Yes.

Comment: Next time, please ask the Google man before you ask us. :)

Comment: It's a raised platform.  And raised platforms are podiums.  In particular this is a competition podium.  Really wish I could answer this question because I'm dieing to post an image of a competition lectern. :)

Comment: This is a podium, but, if you wanted to be more specific, you could also call it a [**medal podium**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1498&bih=855&q=%22medal+podium%22&oq=%22medal+podium%22). In the future, you might want to ask a question like this one on [ell.se].

Comment: Competition podium, medal podium, you could even call it a histogram podium but only your math nerd friends would understand you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is a three–tiered [***rostrum***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rostrum).

> A raised platform on which a person stands to make a public speech, receive an award or medal, play music, or conduct an orchestra:
>   *speaker after speaker stepped up to the rostrum*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rostrum

Answer (score 2):

It is a **[podium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podium)**.

While technically it may also be called a rostrum, podium is the more common term. This has led to the phrase "podium finish" (usually the achievement of finishing in the top 3), and the awful verb "to podium".

Comment: The past participle of the verb "to lead" is "led."